# fade in and out divs in relation to window position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fadein the `<div>`s with class `.cms` and `.seo` when entering the section with id "services" and fadeout when passing that section or before.

I also want it to animate in relation to the scrolling position if its possible.

I give you the link so you can check the site for your self.

For the animations am using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

The javascript code is inside js/agency.js

[Site](http://webcy.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/)

This is the code that I've been trying with..

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y=$(window).scrollTop();
    if (y < 1092){
    $('.cms,.seo').addClass('animated fadeOutRight');  
  }
  if (y > 1092 && y < 1300) {
    $('.cms,.seo').addClass('animated fadeInRight');
  }     
  if (y > 1300){
    $('.cms,.seo').addClass('animated fadeOutRight');  
  }
});
```

I also want to know if it will work on different window sizes or will I have to change the code ?

Thanks!!

Comment: so what exactly goes wrong with your existing code?

Comment: It fades out when scrolling down instead of fading in. And I need it to fadeout when leaving that section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fades out because `if (y < 1092)` will be true as soon as you scroll.

You probably only want to fadeOutRight only if fadeInRight actually exists on the element, that way it won't hide right away, so:

`if (y < 1092 && $('.cms,.seo').hasClass('fadeInRight'))`

Furthermore, since your class animated only specifies how the element is animated, apply this right away to the element instead of appending it with javascript.

See working example on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pjh6gy7e/

It should work on most window sizes unless you change the height of elements responsively.